# C# Check if any string contains in string array and get the value

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am new in c# and  stucked with getting value from arrays. I can check if the string contains any string in array but i have no idea how to get the value of matched string.

In my code i want to get "When is" as a string.

```
string testwords = "When is your birthday";
string[] myStrings = { "Who is ", "When is ", "What is " };

if(myStrings.Any(testwords.Contains))
```

Comment: This might also help you out https://dotnetfiddle.net/UdNrbk

Comment: _"i have no idea how to get the value of matched string"_ -- to do that, you'd have to know the index of the item that matched. And to do that, you can use the `FindIndex()` method. See duplicates. Your predicate might be just like you show above, i.e. `testwords.Contains`.

Comment: @MichaelRandall you are a hero! This is exactly  what i want. Thank you so much!